# Refactoring entity method to avoid concurrency problems

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, concurrency, domain-driven-design

I'm nearing the end of a project for which I'm trying to use DDD, but have discovered a glaring bug that I'm not sure how to easily solve.

Here is my entity - I've reduced it for simplicity:

```
public class Contribution : Entity
{
    protected Contribution()
    {
        this.Parts = new List<ContributionPart>();
    }

    internal Contribution(Guid id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Parts = new List<ContributionPart>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }

    protected virtual IList<ContributionPart> Parts { get; private set; }

    public void UploadParts(string path, IEnumerable<long> partLengths)
    {
        if (this.Parts.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Parts have already been uploaded.");
        }

        long startPosition = 0;
        int partNumber = 1;

        foreach (long partLength in partLengths)
        {
            this.Parts.Add(new ContributionPart(this.Id, partNumber, partLength));
            this.Commands.Add(new UploadContributionPartCommand(this.Id, partNumber, path, startPosition, partLength));
            startPosition += partLength;
            partNumber++;
        }
    }

    public void SetUploadResult(int partNumber, string etag)
    {
        if (etag == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(etag));
        }

        ContributionPart part = this.Parts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PartNumber == partNumber);

        if (part == null)
        {
            throw new ContributionPartNotFoundException(this.Id, partNumber);
        }

        part.SetUploadResult(etag);

        if (this.Parts.All(p => p.IsUploaded))
        {
            IEnumerable<PartUploadedResult> results = this.Parts.Select(p => new PartUploadedResult(p.PartNumber, p.ETag));
            this.Events.Add(new ContributionUploaded(this.Id, results));
        }
    }
}
```

My bug occurs in the SetUploadResult method.  Basically, multiple threads are performing uploads concurrently, and then call SetUploadResult at the end of the upload.  But because the entity was loaded a few seconds beforehand, each thread will be calling SetUploadResult on a different instance of the entity, and so the test `if (this.Parts.All(p => p.IsUploaded)` will never evaluate to true.

I'm not sure how to easily resolve this.  The idea behind adding multiple UploadContributionPartCommands to the Commands collection was so that each ContributionPart could be uploaded in parallel - my CommandBus ensures this - but with each part uploaded in parallel, it causes problems for my entity logic.

Comment: So you are saying that there are multiple threads operating on the same instance of an Contribution entity?

Comment: Correct.  The contribution entity has created an UploadContributionPartCommand for each partLength, and each UploadContributionPartCommandHandler executes in parallel, and as such, makes calls to SetUploadResult in parallel.  Except it's not the same in-memory instance of the entity, but it is the same entity.

Comment: How come it is not the same "in-memory instance" since each instance has its own parts?

Comment: Because each UploadContributionPartCommandHandler uses an IContributionRepository to load the Contribution (via EntityFramework), and EntityFramework will return a different instance of the entity in each thread.

Comment: If every single thread operates on its own instance, where is your issue? What is the shared field/property that may get accessed by several different threads?

Comment: if (this.Parts.All(p => p.IsUploaded)) <--- This will sometimes not evaluate to true, because p.IsUploaded only becomes true when SetUploadResult(int part...) has been called for that part number.  If the final two parts are uploaded at the same time, they will call SetUploadResult in separate threads, but neither will have the update from the other thread, and so the test will evaluate to false on both threads.

Comment: It doesn't sound like DDD that an entity should take care of a crosscutting concern like uploading data. I think the root of your problem is that you're trying to make objects cooperate in parallel actions that shouldn't be their responsibility.

Comment: An Aggregate in DDD should be a "transactional" concept, so it should guarantees concurrency safety on parallels modification. To guarantee it you should have a locking system (optimistic or pessimistic), in a way that the same aggregate CAN'T be modified by concurrent threads.
As @GertArnold said it seems that the command is made just for the upload, why don't you do it inside the aggregate method, executing the upload in parallel and then let the main thread wait all the results? I think it would be the simpler solution...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refactor the `Contribution` so that it will not handle the `SetUploadResult`. It will decouple the Contribution entity and the side effects of the `SetUploadResult` are isolated, keeping the technical concern out of the `Contribution` domain model.

Create a dispatcher class that contains what the `SetUploadResult` is doing.

Once the `Contribution` entity is finished carrying out its logic, the thread of execution will return to the application service. It is at this point that the events from the entity can be fed into the dispatcher.

If they are long running process, you can add them as collection of tasks and run them asynchronously. Then you can just await when all tasks are done. You can search in SO on how to do this.

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2,...taskN);
```

Comment: Agree. Tracking upload progress is definitely an application level concern, not a domain one.

Comment: Fair comment.  We had had so many discussions around contributions and the parts of the contribution that we made the decision to make them part of the domain, but it's reasonable to question whether they should be.

Answer (score 0):

If several threads may call the `SetUploadResult` method simultaneously and you have a race condition your should protect the critical section using a synchronization mechanism such as a lock: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx.

If you make the lock field `static` it will be shared across all instances of your entity type, e.g.:

```
private static readonly object _lock = new object();
public void SetUploadResult(int partNumber, string etag)
{
    if (etag == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(etag));
    }

    ContributionPart part = this.Parts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PartNumber == partNumber);

    if (part == null)
    {
        throw new ContributionPartNotFoundException(this.Id, partNumber);
    }

    part.SetUploadResult(etag);

    lock (_lock) //Only one thread at a time can enter this critical section.
                 //The second thread will wait here until the first thread leaves the critical section.
    {
        if (this.Parts.All(p => p.IsUploaded))
        {
            IEnumerable<PartUploadedResult> results = this.Parts.Select(p => new PartUploadedResult(p.PartNumber, p.ETag));
            this.Events.Add(new ContributionUploaded(this.Id, results));
        }
    }
}
```